# Expanding cross correlation DOA estimation to n microphones

Tags: audio, beamforming, doa

I need to detect the Direction of Arrival of a speech signal using an 8 microphone array as part of a project I've been working on. Currently, I have a working solution in the 2 microphone case:

$$G(\omega ) = X(\omega ) \cdot X_{delayed}^{*}(\omega)$$
$$g(\tau ) = {F}^{-1} [G(\omega)] $$
$$\tau _{max} = argmax\;  g(\tau) $$
$$\theta =  \frac{180}{\pi}\cdot sin^{-1}(\frac{c\, \tau_{max}}{d})$$

To expand this solution to n microphones, I thought about looping across every pair of microphones $nCr = \binom{8}{2}$ and summing the cross correlations computed for each pair  before inverse transforming and locating the peak, however I'm getting incorrect results for my angle.

**My question is :**

Looping across each pair of microphones in the 8 microphone array, calculating the cross correlation of the two signals in the fourier domain, inverse transforming and then summing with the previous loop iterations: Is this the correct method? Am I missing an intermediate step?

Comment: Please repeat your verbal explanation about `calculating the cross correlation ... and then summing with the previous loop iterations`, only this time please use formulas and equations, similar to what you did for the two mic case. I didn't quite catch what you mean. And what 'an intermediate step' are you talking about?